# Magic Mouse 2 stops responding after a while

Tags: mojave, bluetooth, mouse

I just got a Magic Mouse 2 (the Space Gray version) and I've been having some really frustrating issues with it. The sequence of events is the following:

- The mouse will connect just fine, it's recognized and I can even check battery level and rename it
- After 5 min or so it stops recognizing clicks or gestures. It's only capable of moving the cursor.
- If I turn it off and back on it stops working whatsoever
- If I leave the mouse off for a while (like 1hr or so) it starts working again but the whole process repeats itself.

I've tried resetting the device to defaults, resetting the bluetooth module, deleting the bluetooth profiles and other stuff, nothing fixes it.

My set-up:

- MacbookPro 15" 2017
- MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

The issue happens on several machines. I have another Magic Mouse 2 that works just fine and has never had similar issues with this laptop.

Is this a hardware issue?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  If by *The issue happens on several machines* you mean this particular mouse is displaying this problem on multiple Macs, then yes I'd be looking to return it for testing/replacement. You could also give Apple Support a call and go through the process of troubleshooting it with them and if you get no resolution they'll organise for a replacement or visit to an Apple Store (depending on your location, etc).

Comment: Yeah, I sorta came to the same conclusion while writing the question. Still, I was frustrated that there was no similar case posted out there, so in case anyone has the same issue, I'll follow-up with any possible solution.